# How To Fix Unicode/MultiByte Compatibility Issues

Tags: c++

I want to leave my project on multibyte instead of switching it to Unicode. I'm getting some errors trying to make my types work together as follows (VS2019 set to multibye):

The original error is: **argument of type "char *" is incompatible with type "const wchar_t *"** for the following line:

`if (!wcscmp(ModuleEntry.szModule, ModuleName)`

ModuleEntry is of type `MODULEENTRY32`

If I change the type of ModuleEntry to `MODULEENTRY32W` I get the following error:

**Argument type "MODULEENTRY32W" is incompatible with type "LPMODULEENTRY32".**

Here's the full function for reference:

```
DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress(const wchar_t* ModuleName, DWORD ProcessId) {
    MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry = { 0 };
    HANDLE SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessId);

    if (!SnapShot)
        return NULL;

    ModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(ModuleEntry);

    if (!Module32First(SnapShot, &ModuleEntry))
        return NULL;
    do {    
        if (!wcscmp(ModuleEntry.szModule, ModuleName)) {        
            CloseHandle(SnapShot);
            return (DWORD)ModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;
        }   
    } while (Module32Next(SnapShot, &ModuleEntry));

    CloseHandle(SnapShot);
    return NULL;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `wcscmp` is for comparing two Unicode strings. You are comparing a multibyte string (`ModuleEntry.szModule`) with a Unicode string, which won't work. You have a few options. (1) Convert the Unicode string to multibyte before comparing. (2) Convert the multibyte to Unicode before comparing. (2) Use the Unicode versions of the toolhelp functions and structures. (3) Have the caller pass the ModuleName in multibyte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are leaking the `SnapShot` handle if `Module32First()` fails.

Second, you are using the `TCHAR`-based version of the Module32 API, but you are passing in `wchar_t` Unicode data to compare the enumerated module data to.  You have your project setup to MultiByte, which means `TCHAR` maps to `char` and `TCHAR`-based APIs map to ANSI APIs.

So, you are actually calling the **ANSI** version of the Module32 API, ie `MODULEENTRY32` maps to `MODULEENTRY32A`, and `Module32First()`/`Module32Next()` map to `Module32FirstA()`/`Module32NextA()`.

You cannot pass `char` data to `wcscmp()`, and you cannot pass `wchar_t` data to `strcmp()`.  So, if you continue using the ANSI APIs, then you MUST perform a data conversion at runtime in one direction or the other, either to:

- convert the `char` module data to `wchar_t` via `MultiByteToWieChar()`
- convert the `wchar_t` comparison data to `char` via `WideCharToMultiByte()`

Only then can you use an appropriate function to compare the two datas.

Since you are passing in `wchar_t` data for comparison, you should *explicitly* call the **Unicode** version of the Module32 API, not the `TCHAR` version.  You do not have to set the whole project to Unicode in order to use Unicode APIs, eg:

```c
void* GetModuleBaseAddress(const wchar_t* ModuleName, DWORD ProcessId)
{
    HANDLE SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessId);
    if (SnapShot)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32W ModuleEntry = { 0 };
        ModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(ModuleEntry);

        if (Module32FirstW(SnapShot, &ModuleEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (wcscmp(ModuleEntry.szModule, ModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    CloseHandle(SnapShot);
                    return ModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;
                }   
            }
            while (Module32NextW(SnapShot, &ModuleEntry));
        }

        CloseHandle(SnapShot);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation and code sample. Very helpful.